# Why won't this wall break?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I found a secret wall in *Enter the Gungeon.* I know the starting gun can't uncover secret walls, but I found a handy mermaid shotgun that can, and did, reveal the breakable wall to me. However, the gun doesn't seem to want to actually *destroy* the wall.

I've tried my only other gun, the one that specifically says it *can't* break walls, but other than that, I'm out of options, since rolling into it does nothing.

How do I get through this thing?

[image]

Comment: I've seen a bomb for sale in the shop; I'll wait to answer until I can confirm, but I'll bet that's it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fire off a blank, one of your blue bullets.  Using a controller that's clicking LS and RS at the same time.

Comment: Using a keyboard + mouse, it's the Q key.

Comment: Judging by the screen shot in the question, the player has the [brick of cash](http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Brick_of_Cash) item, which causes that little gray being to point out secret door locations as well. It's worth noting that exposing the crack in the wall is not required to break it with a blank.